# How to constrain a parameter pack to a single type?

Tags: c++, c++20

```
struct moveonly{
    moveonly(){}
    moveonly(moveonly&& o){}
    moveonly(const moveonly&)=delete;
};

template<class Arg>
void multi(const Arg&... in){}

int main(...){
    moveonly i,j,k;
    multi(i,j,k);
}
```

doesn't compile, but putting `class...Arg` instead of `class Arg` in the template arguments makes it compile at the cost of allowing input parameters of different types. how can I make sure all arguments are same type? if I know the type will always be `moveonly`, how can I make sure all input to `multi()` is that specific class?

not asking for opinions if c++ standard did do something wrong here! I'm asking about best practice here. what boilerplate snippet do you use in such cases? I tried various things and learned that ellipsis in parameter-list is handled differently from rest of program, likely due to c-heritage of that operator and the different nature of the comma-operator there, which only added in confusion...

I am sure one could do something with concepts, such answers are welcome too. haven't looked into it though, looking for simpler solutions.

Comment: There are no fold expressions here.

Comment: *"How to constrain a parameter pack to a single type?"* In some cases, the best is the alternative to use `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Why would you want them all to be the same type?  Imagine the equivalent of int, short, short, unsigned int is passed.

Answer (score 4):

Use C++20 concept [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) to constrain `Arg` to be `moveonly` only:

```
#include <concepts>

template<std::same_as<moveonly>... Arg>
void multi(const Arg&... in) {}

// Alternative ways to apply the same constraint:

// void multi(const std::same_as<moveonly> auto&... in) {}

// template<class... Arg>
//   requires (std::same_as<moveonly, Arg> && ...)
// void multi(const Arg&... in) {}
```